# How to pass exporting objects in spreasheet gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spreadsheet

I want to export data after AJAX search, so I created such action(search conditions will be added after I could make downloading work):

```
 def export

  require 'spreadsheet'

  @data = Item.all

  report = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new

  sheet = report.create_worksheet :name => "data"

  spreadsheet = StringIO.new 
  report.write spreadsheet 
  send_data spreadsheet.string, :filename => "report.xls", :type =>  "application/vnd.ms-excel"

 end
```

And file is empty. How I can pass objects ?

Answer (score 0):

For the future ME:

```
 @data = Item.all

 report = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new

 sheet = report.create_worksheet :name => "data"

 sheet.row(0).concat %w{Id CreatedAt}
 @data.each_with_index { |item, i|
       sheet.row(i+1).push item.id,item.created_at
    }
```